# setState in action handler using ReactJS not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React.

I have a handler, as follows, that updates state of an array.  The data is a set of animal pairs.

```
class Animal extends Component {
    state = {
        pairs: [
            { fromAnimal: 'Dog', toAnimal: 'Cat' },
            { fromAnimal: 'Lion', toAnimal: 'Tiger' },
            { fromAnimal: 'Rabbit', toAnimal: 'Bear' }
        ]
    };

    closePairHandler = (fromAnimal, toAnimal) => {
        let newPairs = this.state.pairs.filter((pair) => {
            return !(pair.fromAnimal === fromAnimal && pair.toAnimal === toAnimal);
        });

        console.log('pairs', newPairs); // This shows that the correct pair was removed from the array.

        this.setState({ pairs: newPairs });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.pairs.map((pair, index) => {
                        return <SomeComponent key={index} pair={pair} closePair={(fromAnimal, toAnimal) => this.closePairHandler(fromAnimal, toAnimal)} />;
                    }
                }
            </div>
        );
    };
};

export default Animal;
```

This is a super simplified version of the code I have.  BUT, when the closePairHandler is called to remove an animal pair (for example, Lion/Tiger).  The `console.log` in the `closePairHandler` shows that the array has been updated successfully.

However, when the components render. It is removing the LAST component in the array and not the one that was selected.  It's reducing the array size by 1, but not removing the correct item in the mapping (in render), althought the closePairHandler `console.log` is showing the array correctly updated before setting the state.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please add `SomeComponent ` as well

Comment: See here about using the indexes as keys: https://www.menubar.io/react-keys-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing the key for your mapped data while rendering `SomeComponent` and hence react is not able to correctly identify what element got changed. You can use `index as the key` if you don't have a `unique id` in your pair object else you should use that for performance reasons

```
return (
        <div>
            {
                this.state.pairs.map((pair, index) => {
                    return <SomeComponent key={index} pair={pair} closePair={(fromAnimal, toAnimal) => this.closePairHandler(fromAnimal, toAnimal)} />;
                }
            }
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Sorry took a min to respond.  My real code is using a "key" in the map and it is still happening.  I've updated the code example above to reflect it.